# Same question, different review queues

Tags: discussion, review, flags, low-quality-posts

More and more often on the Security SE website, I get the same question to review in the "Low Quality" queue, and also the "First Posts" queue?

As a result I often end up first recommending deletion/closure, and then flagging the question as low quality. Shouldn't flagging disqualify me from recommending deletion and vice versa?